# Variants dont show their individual reference numbers

Tags: javascript, php, prestashop, prestashop-1.7

In my product settings I can choose individual reference numbers for my variant. But on the product pages in my shop theres always only the main reference number of the product which does not change when switching the variant.
I found this in my product-details.tpl:

```
{if isset($product.reference_to_display) && $product.reference_to_display neq ''}
  <div class="product-reference">
    <label class="label">{l s='Reference' d='Shop.Theme.Catalog'} </label>
    <span itemprop="sku">{$product.reference_to_display}</span>
  </div>
{/if}
```

Is there any method to make the number change when switching product variant? Im using version 1.7.6

Comment: It should change by default. Do you use a specific theme? Can you check your console if it displays any errors?